# Laravel Eloquent Model Unit testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, eloquent

I am trying to write a testcase which tests the association and detachment of the relationship between two Eloquent models in Laravel 4.2

Here's my test case:

```
class BookingStatusSchemaTest extends TestCase
{

  private $statusText = "Confirmed";
  private $bookingStub;
  private $statusStub;

  public function testMigrateService()
  {

    $this->createTestData();

    $booking = $this->bookingStub;
    $status = $this->statusStub;

    /**
     * Check that the booking has no status. OK
     */
    $this->assertNull($booking->status);

    /**
     * Check that status has no booking. OK
     */
    $this->assertEquals(count($status->bookings), 0);

    /**
     * Add a status to the booking. OK
     */
    $booking->status()->associate($this->statusStub);

    /**
     * Check that status has a booking. NOT OK - This gives error
     */
    $this->assertEquals(count($status->bookings), 1);

    /**
     * Check that the booking has a status. OK
     */
    $this->assertNotNull($booking->status);

    /**
     * Do NOT delete the status, just set the reference
     * to it to null.
     */
    $booking->status = null;

    /**
     * And check again. OK
     */
    $this->assertNull($booking->status);
  }

  private function createTestData()
  {

    $bookingStatus = BookingStatus::create([ 
        'status' => $this->statusText 
    ]);

    $booking = Booking::create([ ]);

    $this->bookingStub = $booking;
    $this->statusStub = $bookingStatus;

  }

}
```

When I execute it I get:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) BookingStatusSchemaTest::testMigrateService
Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 0.
```

Booking model:

```
class Booking extends Eloquent {

  /**
  * A booking have a status
  */
  public function status()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('BookingStatus');
  }

}
```

BookingStatus Model:

```
class BookingStatus extends Eloquent
{
  protected $table = 'booking_statuses';
  protected $guarded = [ 'id' ];
  protected $fillable = ['status'];

  /**
   * A booking status belongs to a booking
   */
  public function bookings()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Booking');
  }

}
```

Here's the migration Schema for bookingstatus:

```
  Schema::create('booking_statuses', function(Blueprint $table)
  {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->timestamps();
  });
```

And heres for booking:

```
Schema::create('bookings', function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->unsignedInteger('booking_status_id')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

What do I have to add / change to be able to verify the relationship in my test case?

Comment: This is because `$testBooking->status` is never null, it's an [Illuminate\Support\Collection](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) - that's what you get when you access a *relationship* as a property. A collection is never null, but it can be empty, you can check this with `$testBooking->status->isEmpty()` (returns boolean) or just treat it like an array: `$this->assertCount(0, $testBooking->status);`.

Comment: But `echo $testBooking->status->status;` gives `Confirmed` , so I don't think it's deleted..

Comment: Ok, that's indeed a little weird. Another thing I've noticed: In your `createTestData` it looks like you expect the id to be returned from the `save()`-method - that's not the case, `save()` returns a boolean indicating if everything went fine. In your case it didn't blow up yet because the boolean is probably casted to 1 within the `find()`-method. Could you please do a `var_dump($this->bookingId, $this->statusId)` in the test-method to check that. Not sure if this is the culprit, but you should fix it anyway. Did that change anything?

Comment: Also, when updating a `belongsTo`-relationship it should be: `$booking->status()->associate($bookingStatus);` - And should a booking status not "blong to many" bookings..?

Comment: Ok about the id and the save, you were right. It casted boolean true to id 1. I have fixed that now.
You are also right about the belongsToMany. I also updated the model to this. However when I try `$booking->status()->associate($bookingStatus);` I get this error: `1) BookingStatusSchemaTest::testMigrateService
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()`

Comment: Yeah, the error is because now it's a `belongsToMany`-relationship, so you have to use `save()` instead of `associate()`.

Comment: Actually, after looking closer at it, your DB-design seems a little bit off. The `bookings`-table should hold the foireign key 'booking_status_id' and should definitely *not* cascade on delete - if you delete a booking, you do not want to delete the related status, because other bookings may be associated with that status. So: `Booking` *belongsTo* `BookingStatus`, and `BookingStatus` *hasMany* `Booking` (`belongsToMany` might sound more natural, but that's for many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: I've created a little [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cnuaui6q) where I've rewritten the test (assuming you changed the model-relationships as described above). Honestly, it doesn't seem to make much sense to me. The only thing you're testing with that is Eloquent's functionality which has already been tested. Also, it wouldn't make much sense for a booking to have no status, I guess. Or maybe I just don't get the whole context :)

Comment: OK thanks for all the input. I have now made som updates to both models and migrations. Still cant get it to work. Why I write this test? I develop by the tdd principle. Thus writing my tests first, and then writing code to make the tests green. Maybe they dont make sense, but to me it does :) I want to test the event of deleting a bookingStatus. Not setting the reference to null. I want the data in the booking_status table to be deleted. I have updated my question above with all the new code. Appreciate if you or someone else could help me a bit more.

Comment: The error I get is still the same, that the bookingStatus is not deleted it's still there and I can echo $booking->status->status and I get output "Confirmed"

Comment: Ok, I've recreated the setup localy - it works fine for me, the test returns green. The migrations: http://pastebin.com/02rZWJhD | http://pastebin.com/cUGAvEW3, the models: http://pastebin.com/D8C03jSq | http://pastebin.com/W7LRm90S and the test: http://pastebin.com/nFn9YQDi - Run `composer dump-auto -o` and `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan optimize` to make sure that eveything is flushed and reloaded.

Comment: Sorry, totally overlooked your explaining comment above. Yeah, TDD is fine, but: You should only test things that you *own*. You do not own the Eloquent functionality, so you should not be the one testing it. What you want to do instead is test your own functionality (which may encapsulate Eloquent), e.g. create methods like `setStatus(BookingStatus $status)` and `removeStatus()` on your `Booking`-model and test them. And concerning the deletion: Yeah, that seems to be an issue actually, but in fact, that's **not** how it's supposed to be used. I'll try to explain:

Comment: The BookingStatus is referenced by a booking_status_id from your Booking. If you delete the associated BookingStatus, the booking_status_id still stays in the Booking-table but now references an unexistent record on another table. Your data integrity is not valid anymore, unless you set the booking_status_id to NULL yourself. But you have to do this on the application level, i.e. in your Booking-model. And yes, after `$booking->status()->delete()` you can still reference the status, but probably from memory, and `BookingStatus::all()` would actually give you an empty result after that.

Comment: The thing is: If you do `$booking->status->delete()` and then `$booking->status`, your application should actually break because you're referencing a non-existent model. But if you set `$booking->status = null;` you're in a valid state again. No reference is perfectly valid, a non-existent reference is not. Maybe you just misunderstood the concept of `delete()` a little: It deletes *models* (a.k.a. table rows), not relationships, because that again would violate your data integrity.

Comment: And btw: This example does not make much sense because if you want to delete the status as soon as a booking is deleted, that would actually make it a 1:1 relationship and the booking-status would actually be a field on the booking table. It simply makes no sense, neither from the domain point of view nor from the database design perspective. And then you end up on StackOverflow, wondering what's going on :-D

Comment: FIrst of all. THank you very much for helping me, really appreciate it. I understand some things much better now that you have explained them to me. Unfortunately it still doesnt work. I have copied your code from pastebin and they all work. I added one more assetion which is critical for me: `$this->assertEquals(count($status->bookings), 1);` To check if the statusStub has any assigned bookings. And it doesnt. It gives an empty collection array. I have updated my question above with all of my code. I just cant figure this out.

Comment: That's because you're still working with instances you've created in your `createTestData()` method. They were loaded with the properties at that time. **1.)** you have to `save()` the booking after you associated the status to persist the change. **2.)** You have to "reload" (i.e. fetch a new instance of) your `$status`, e.g. with `$status = BookingStatus::first();` to get the bookings, or at least trigger a new query to fetch the bookings: `$status->load('bookings');` or `$status->bookings()->get()`. And **3.)** You would (hopefully) never do things like this in a real application!

Comment: And I really, really, REALLY highly recommend to just pick an example-application that is closer to the real world - why not just play around with the obligatory blog application, with users, posts and comments (and tons of tutorials and examples). And *please* stop testing Eloquent's functionality. Tests like these do not benefit you in any way because you're testing third party code you have no control over. This is actually bad practice and does not really have anything to do with TDD! Write tests for **your own** methods/classes!

Comment: But I am testing my own functions. `return $this->belongsTo('BookingStatus'); ` is one example code inside a function that needs to be tested. I need to verify that for example I didn't mistype 'BookinStatus' or mistyped belongsTo, I am testing my code with integration tests, I dont see why this shouldn't be relevant

Comment: Whoa, that sure is one late comment :-D But I'm in! If you want to test if Booking and BookingStatus are wired up correctly, you create a Booking and an associated BookingStatus in your test DB and then check for something like `$this->assertEquals($booking->status->id, $someExpectedId)`. Think of it as a feature: `I can get the booking status of a booking`. You test the **feature**, you don't care how it's implemented, because implementation may change over time. And there is really no need to stub the involved classes, just use the real ones. Laravel's model factories make this a breeze.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> It's been a while and I had totally forgotten about this question.
>   Since OP still sems interested in it, I'll try to answer the question
>   in some way.

So I assume the actual task is: **How to test the correct relationship between two Eloquent models?**

I think it was Adam Wathan who first suggested abandoning terms like "Unit Tests" and "Functional Tests" and "I-have-no-idea-what-this-means Tests" and just separate tests into two concerns/concepts: Features and Units, where Features simply describe features of the app, like "A logged in user can book a flight ticket", and Units describe the lower level Units of it and the functionality they expose, like "A booking has a status".

I like this approach a lot, and with that in mind, I'd like to refactor your test:

```
class BookingStatusSchemaTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function a_booking_has_a_status()
    {
        // Create the world: there is a booking with an associated status
        $bookingStatus = BookingStatus::create(['status' => 'confirmed']);
        $booking = Booking::create(['booking_status_id' => $bookingStatus->id]);

        // Act: get the status of a booking
        $actualStatus = $booking->status;

        // Assert: Is the status I got the one I expected to get?
        $this->assertEquals($actualStatus->id, $bookingStatus->id);
    }


    /** @test */    
    public function the_status_of_a_booking_can_be_revoked()
    {
        // Create the world: there is a booking with an associated status
        $bookingStatus = BookingStatus::create(['status' => 'confirmed']);
        $booking = Booking::create(['booking_status_id' => $bookingStatus->id]);

        // Act: Revoke the status of a booking, e.g. set it to null
        $booking->revokeStatus();

        // Assert: The Status should be null now
        $this->assertNull($booking->status);
    }
}
```

*This code is not tested!*

Note how the function names read like a description of a Booking and its functionality. You don't really care about the implementation, you don't have to know where or how the Booking gets its BookingStatus - you just want to make sure that if there is Booking with a BookingStatus, you can get that BookingStatus. Or revoke it. Or maybe change it. Or do whatever. Your test shows how you'd like to interact with this Unit. So write the test and then try to make it pass.

The main flaw in your test is probably that you're kind of "afraid" of some magic to happen. Instead, think of your models as Plain Old PHP Objects - because that's what they are! And you wouldn't run a test like this on a POPO:

```
/**
 * Do NOT delete the status, just set the reference
 * to it to null.
 */
$booking->status = null;

/**
 * And check again. OK
 */
$this->assertNull($booking->status);
```

It's a really broad topic and every statement about it inevitably opinioted. There are some guidelines that help you get along, like "only test your own code", but it's really hard to put all the peaces together. Luckily, the aforementioned Adam Wathan has a really excellent video course named "[Test Driven Laravel](https://adamwathan.me/test-driven-laravel/)" where he test-drives a whole real-world Laravel application. It may be a bit costly, but it's worth every penny and helps you understand testing way more than some random dude on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thank you,for taking time on replying. Yes it was a while since I replied to this question, it just happened to popup in my mind today :)
I agree with the $booking->status = null. That doesnt make sense. Its better with a method on the model for this type of revokation, as you suggested. But apart from the naming of the test, and the status=null. I think we both agree that its actually useful to have these types of tests in some form. If you call them integration or feature tests is not important to me.The importance is to test precisely what you describe in your refactored test.

Comment: Im giving you the accepted answer to this question, because I agree with your answer totally, and we both agree this is the way you should test eloquent relationships in order to verify that the logic isn't broken by mistake

Comment: @henrik *"I think we both agree that its actually useful to have these types of tests in some form*" - absolutely! The main point is to abstract the test from the implementation. By using things like `$booking->associate()` in your test, you assume that you're dealing with an Eloquent model and that this is the only way to connect a Booking and a BookingStatus. You're introducing a method that you don't own in your test. But all you want to do is make sure that `$booking->status` gives you the status if there is one. But yeah, you get the point! Good luck and keep testing :)

Comment: Oh, and I forgot the usual disclaimer: It depends!™ :) I think any test is fine for small projects. Also, if you know for sure that it will always be powered by Laravel, then I think there is really nothing wrong with explicitly using Laravel functionality in your tests. Eloquent is just a DB-abstraction, so why not just skip it and write directly to the DB? It just looks weird to me and I try to avoid it as much as possible. But, as always: It depends :)

Answer (score 7):

To test you're setting the correct Eloquent relationship, you have to run assertions against the relationship class (`$model->relation()`). 
You can assert

- It's the correct relationship type by asserting `$model->relation()` is an instance of `HasMany`, `BelongsTo`, `HasManyThrough`... etc
- It's relating to the correct model by using `$model->relation()->getRelated()`
- It's using the correct foreign key by using `$model->relation()->getForeignKey()`
- The foreign key exists as a column in the table by using `Schema::getColumListing($table)` (Here, `$table` is either `$model->relation()->getRelated()->getTable()` if it's a `HasMany` relationship or `$model->relation()->getParent()->getTable()` if it's a `BelongsTo` relationship)

For example. Let's say you've got a `Parent` and a `Child` model where a `Parent` has many `Child` through the `children()` method using `parent_id` as foreign key. `Parent` maps the `parents` table and `Child` maps the `children` table.

```php
$parent = new Parent;
# App\Parent
$parent->children()
# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
$parent->children()->getRelated()
# App\Child
$parent->children()->getForeignKey()
# 'parent_id'
$parent->children()->getRelated()->getTable()
# 'children'
Schema::getColumnListing($parent->children()->getRelated()->getTable())
# ['id', 'parent_id', 'col1', 'col2', ...]
```

**EDIT** 
Also, this does not touch the database since we're never saving anything. However, the database needs to be migrated or the models will not be associated with any tables.

Comment: From the api documentation. I just looked at what methods were public.